# ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument a component with children - children seem to "not render in DOM"

Tags: html, css, unit-testing, reactjs, reactjs-testutils

I render a component in my test like so:

```
component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
  <SlidingContainer {...props}>
    <div style={divStyle}>foo</div>
    <div style={divStyle}>foo</div>
    <div style={divStyle}>foo</div>
  </SlidingContainer>
);

$bodyElement = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component.refs.body));
```

This is from `SlidingContainer`'s render method

```
return (
  <div className={rootClassName} >
    <div className="sliding-container_arrow sliding-container_arrow--left"
         onClick={this.slide.bind(this, 'left')}>
      <div className={leftArrowClassName}></div>
    </div>
    <div className="sliding-container_body" ref="body">
      { this.props.children }
    </div>
    <div className="sliding-container_arrow sliding-container_arrow--right"
         onClick={this.slide.bind(this, 'right')}>
      <div className={rightArrowClassName}></div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

As you can see, `$bodyElement` is a DOM element that contains the children. It has a set width, whitespace: nowrap, overflow: hidden

This is `updateScrollState` method of `SlidingContainer'

```
updateScrollState($bodyElement) {
  var bodyElement = $bodyElement[0];
  var maxScrollLength = bodyElement.scrollWidth - bodyElement.offsetWidth;
  let maxToTheRight = maxScrollLength === $bodyElement.scrollLeft()
  let maxToTheLeft = $bodyElement.scrollLeft() === 0;

  this.setState({
    maxToTheRight: maxToTheRight,
    maxToTheLeft: maxToTheLeft
  });
}
```

This code works when I test it in the browser, but when running the karma/jasmine unit tests, `bodyElement.scrollWidth` and `bodyElement.offsetWidth` both equal 0. I searched around, and it seems this is an issue with an element being rendered in memory only and without real DOM, even though `renderIntoDocument` is supposed to render the element into a dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount it to DOM. Use `window.body.appendChild($bodyElement)`